# Ada arrays of access type

Tags: c, ada, function-call

Ada Coders,

I am trying to pass an array of pointers to a C function from Ada. I am new to Ada.

Here's the code:

```
with Interfaces.C; use Interfaces.C;
with asm_generic_int_ll64_h; use asm_generic_int_ll64_h;

block : array(Integer range 1 .. 6) of access uu_u8;
one : aliased uu_u8 := uu_u8(1);
two : aliased uu_u8 := uu_u8(2);
three : aliased uu_u8 := uu_u8(3);
four : aliased uu_u8 := uu_u8(4);
five : aliased uu_u8 := uu_u8(5);
six : aliased uu_u8 := uu_u8(6);

ans : uu_u8;

begin

block(1) := one'Access;
block(2) := two'Access;
block(3) := three'Access;
block(4) := four'Access;
block(5) := five'Access;
block(6) := six'Access;

call_c_func(block(1));

ans := block(1).all;
```

The last line causes an error:

> raised STORAGE_ERROR : stack overflow (or erroneous memory access)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show us the signature of the C function and your import statement for the function. Also the definition of the type `uu_u8`.

Comment: The signature of the C function: __s32 read_i2c_block_data(int file, __u8 command, __u8 length, __u8 *values)

Comment: import statement: with i2c_interface_c; use i2c_interface_c;

Comment: definition of uu_u8:   subtype uu_s8 is signed_char;

Comment: If the signature has a return value, your import is wrong because as you call it, `call_c_func` is a procedure when it needs to be a function. Your import statement is the subprogram definition of `call_c_func` on the Ada side, not some `with` statement. We do not know the contents of `i2c_interface_c`, you need to show it.

Comment: Simon, when I add all to the declaration of block I get:  "all" is not permitted for anonymous access types

Comment: Also, the list of arguments on the C side does not match at all with the single parameter you call it with on the Ada side.

Comment: Here it is flyx:  function read_i2c_block_data
     (file : int;
      command : asm_generic_int_ll64_h.uu_u8;
      length : asm_generic_int_ll64_h.uu_u8;
      values : access asm_generic_int_ll64_h.uu_u8) return asm_generic_int_ll64_h.uu_s32;  -- i2c_interface.c:90
   pragma Import (C, read_i2c_block_data, "read_i2c_block_data");

Comment: Well that's not `call_c_func`, is it? It has a different number of parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to be brief. Here is the actual way I call the function: result := read_i2c_block_data(Interfaces.C.int(fd), uu_u8(LSM9DS0_OUT_X_L_M), uu_u8(block'Length), block(1));

Comment: You should read up how to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The call to the C function executes. The error occurs when I try to access the block array.

Comment: It’d help if you edited the question in a coherent way instead of teasing us with random snippets of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments, it is clear that you use a wrong array type.

Your array on the Ada side is an array of pointers to `uu_8`. However, on the C side, `__u8*` is expected, i.e. a pointer to a `__u8` value. The types are not compatible.

In C, arrays are typically passed as pointer to the first element. This is the case here. So what you actually need on the Ada side is an array with `uu_8` values in it:

```
type My_Array is array (Integer range <>) of uu_8;
pragma Convention (C, My_Array);

Block : My_Array := (1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3, 4 => 4, 5 => 5, 6 => 6);

function read_i2c_block_data
  (file : int;
   command : asm_generic_int_ll64_h.uu_u8;
   length : asm_generic_int_ll64_h.uu_u8;
   values : in out My_Array) return asm_generic_int_ll64_h.uu_s32;
pragma Import (C, read_i2c_block_data, "read_i2c_block_data");
```

The compiler will map your Ada array to a pointer to the first element when having convention C and used in a function imported with C calling convention. `in out` tells Ada that the C function may modify the array.